# Unlinking a locally cloned repository from its GitHub origin

Tags: git, github

I had a GitHub repository which I decided to delete but continue to maintain only as a local repo on my hard drive. I am now left with the locally cloned repo which maintains all the history and that's fine. However, a number of configuration settings remain that point to the (now deleted) GitHub repo.
E.g:

```
$ grep github .git/*
.git/config:    url = https://github.com/foo/bar.git
.git/FETCH_HEAD:07c0bac92a829f3acb4b2f5c112de5f787f046e4        branch 'master' of https://github.com/foo/bar
```

What should I do to ensure that my local repo contains no dangling references and that I cannot push upstream from it anymore nor fetch into it? (how do we call such a repo that doesn't have a remote origin?)
It is not clear to me which settings to delete / update and which values to use.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Issuing

```
git remote rm origin
```

will delete the config settings from `.git/config`.

Then issue

```
rm .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

to get rid of the `FETCH_HEAD` which still points to github.

---

However, as @gturri said even if those settings are present, your local copy is already "uncoupled" from the github repository. This is because you deleted the remote repository and every action like `push/pull/fetch` would lead to an error therefore.

Comment: I just wanted to clear up the settings. I understand it is "uncoupled" since you can't be coupled to something that no longer exists - unless the "deleted" github repo still exists or rather lingers in some capacity and may be retrieved or revived which I understand is not the case, right?

Comment: yes, right. Settings should been gone away after issuing those commands?

Comment: 1st command succeeds; 2nd fails with: "error: branch 'FETCH_HEAD' not found."

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Oh I see. Then I would delete the file manually using `rm .git/FETCH_HEAD`. Will update the answer.

Comment: How to unlink the repository if I have deleted all the git files in it using git -rm rf command?

Comment: That's unlinked, the hard way ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you've deleted Github's repo, you already can't push or fetch from it (it would yield an error)

However, you should remove the reference to the Github repo:

```
git remote remove origin
```